# Testing rails controller with nested resource and private method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I've looked around several questions on SO and can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a simple rails controller. with a new method and private method:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_bar

  def new
    @foo = @bar.foos.build
  end

  private

  def load_bar
    @bar = Bar.find params[:bar_id]
  end
end
```

How do I properly test the new method, and should I be testing the load_bar method? I'm currently doing the following, but it doesn't feel quite right:

```
describe FooController do
  let(:bar) { create(:bar) }

  context 'GET new' do
    let(:foo) { mock_model(Foo) }

    it 'should assign a @foo' do
      Bar.should_receive(:find).and_return(bar)
      bar.stub_chain(:foos, :build).and_return(foo)

      get :new, bar_id: bar
      assigns(:foo).should == foo
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that is enough to test this action:

```
describe FooController do
  describe "GET 'new'" do
    let(:bar) { create :bar }

    it "assigns bar" do
      get :new, bar_id: bar.to_param # Or bar.id
      expect(assigns[:bar]).to eq(bar)
    end
    it "assigns a new foo" do
      get :new, bar_id: bar.to_param
      expect(assigns[:foo]).to be_a_new(Foo)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems easy enough. I thought I might be overthinking it.